# Exception happened during processing of request

Tags: python

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.227.112', 49343)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 283, in _handle_request_noblock
        self.process_request(request, client_address)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 309, in process_request
        self.finish_request(request, client_address)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 322, in finish_request
        self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 617, in __init__
        self.handle()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 130, in handle
        self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 444, in readline
        data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

The code block somewhere. Then I have to press  <kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd> to kill the block point, so that the program can run continue. If the block happened, the program became very slow. Can anybody have good suggestions to solve this?

Comment: This is the bug in python version 2.6, update your python. mine is working with 3.4.4 version.

Answer (score -2):

How about this?
you can put `excepion` when an error occurs.

for example script:

```
try:
   ...first_conditional

except KeyboardInterrupt:
   ...your_optional_conditional
```

Check this docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt